# How to remove ticks outside intervals ends

Tags: ticks, statistics

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{statistics}
\begin{document}
    \StatsRangeData \tips = { 15.95, 12.60, 20.75, 22.20, 8.80, 15.60, 19.50, 20.60, 24.15, 9.85, 11.80, 12.75, 15.40, 16.90, 18.45, 17.10, 14.35, 23.30, 9.20, 16.80, 5.45, 5.40, 7.80, 28.85, 9.25 }
    (\IN[5;9;[, \IN[9;13;[, \IN[13;17;[, \IN[17;21;[, \IN[21;25;[, \IN[25;29;[)
    %\detokenize\expandafter{\tips}
    \statisticssetup{graph/values=Classes}
    \statisticssetup[graph]{counts=Counts}
    \StatsGraph \tips[ x/axis = {ticks={major={at={5, 9, 13,17,21,25,29}}}, grid = none}, y/axis = {grid = none}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Want to remove ticks outside intervals ends]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove minor ticks in `x` axis!!!

```
    \documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{statistics}
    \StatsRangeData \tips = { 15.95, 12.60, 20.75, 22.20, 8.80, 15.60, 19.50, 20.60, 24.15, 9.85, 11.80, 12.75, 15.40, 16.90, 18.45, 17.10, 14.35, 23.30, 9.20, 16.80, 5.45, 5.40, 7.80, 28.85, 9.25 }
(\IN[5.0;9.0;[, \IN[9;13;[, \IN[13;17;[, \IN[17;21;[, \IN[21;25;[, \IN[25;29;])
%\detokenize\expandafter{\tips}
\statisticssetup{graph/values=Classes}
\statisticssetup[graph]{counts=Counts}
\begin{document}
    \StatsGraph \tips[ 
        x/axis = { 
            ticks={
                major={at={ 5.0, 9.0, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29 }}, 
                minor={style={draw=none}}
            }, 
            grid = none
        }, 
        y/axis = {
            grid = none
        }
    ]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

If Yes correct the last line of Your's code this way:

```
\StatsGraph \tips[ x/axis = {ticks={major={at={5, 9, 13,17,21,25,29}}}, grid = none}, y/axis = {grid = none},axissystem={end labels, clean}]
```

**EDIT**: The better I can have is this graph:

[image]

with this last line of code:

```
\StatsGraph \tips[x/axis = {grid = none}, axissystem={end labels, clean}, y/axis = {grid = none},axissystem={end labels, clean}]
```

Comment: Nice, you got rid of the upper ones, but the x-axis ones are still there, those in the Classes.

Comment: In the last edition you lost the ends of the intervals of the classes :(

Comment: @tatojo No it's correct. If I add what You say I have an error.

Comment: The point is to have ticks in the ends of intervals [5,9[, [9,13[, [13,17[, [17,21[, [21,25[ and [25,29]. And to get rid of the others.